# Apply zscore normalization for specific dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I use the following approach to normalized any dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=0)  # Remove NaNs
df = df.apply(zscore)  # Normalization
```

This code performs normalization for **all** columns. If I want to perform normalization for specific columns from a total 24 columns, say only `['Col_1', 'Col_5', 'Col_21']`, how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: `df[col_list] = df[col_list].apply(zscore)`

Comment: I've closed your problem because it is a trivial indexing issue.

Comment: Oh right, I am sorry for that. I guess I need more sleep